# identify mouse click vs keyboard shortcut on menu item

Tags: vb.net, winforms, menuitem

I am on vb.net 2010. In my winforms application I have a menuItem click event handler which can be invoked by mouse click or by keyboard shortcut keys. How do I tell in my handler was called from mouse click vs keyboard shortcut key

```
Private Sub myToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myMenuItemClick
   Dim MouseClicked As Boolean 
   MouseClicked = ?? how to make the distinction how handler was called ?? 
   If MouseClicked Then
      lblClicked.Text = "Mouse Click" 
   Else
      lblClicked.Text = "Key board shortcut" 
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Plutonix: I want some action to be performed only if it was invoked through keyboard shortcut. How would you make the distinction can you specify more with the menuopening event

Comment: if you want different things to happen, you should use 2 methods, with one calling the other perhaps (less confusing to the user).  You *might* be able to set a flag in the dropdownopening event which would get set when they click. but they could also use the Alt key to open the menu and Arrow to the selection or open the top level menu with its short cut key which would open the menu and set the flag.

Comment: As an app user, I would be _very_ confused and annoyed at different behaviors between keyboard shortcut and mouse click.  What about touch screens?  Would they have different behavior as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) of form and check for shortcut, and if the shortcut was pressed, return true. This way the click only will raise by click not by shortcut:

```
Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click

    MessageBox.Show("Click")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) _
    As Boolean

    If (Me.NewToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = keyData) Then
        MessageBox.Show("ShortCut")
        Return True
    End If
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
End Function
```

Comment: Works in general, but there are user actions that can break this, such as MouseDown on the button and then move the mouse away before MouseUp, then use the keyboard shortcut.  You can fix that by setting mouseDown = false in the button's MouseLeave handler.

Comment: @TonyHinkle You are right, but it could't fix that way. Because you may down, then leave (still down), then enter, then up.

Comment: @TonyHinkle I edited the answer, hope you find it useful:)